# Is the derivative of the function bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

If a function has an oblique or horizontal asymptote but doesn't have any vertical asymptote, then can we say that the derivative of the function is bounded?

This question came in my mind while I was studying real analysis, geometrically I am able to see that it might happen but am not able to give any analytical proof.

Comment: Also, going along the lines of the example by @GoodMorningCaptain, if you want a $C^{\infty}$ version, consider $f(x) = \sin(e^x)$. Then $f$ is bounded by $1$, however, its derivative $f'(x) = e^x \cos(e^x)$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you restrict yourself to the case: "If a function has an horizontal or slant asymptote at $+\infty$ (or $-\infty$), there is a neighborhood of $+\infty$ (or $-\infty$) where the derivative is bounded", the statement is false.

Consider the function

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin x^3}x$$

(horizontal asymptote), or

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin x^3}x + x$$

(slant asymptote).

As an exercise you can show that, in the latter case, 
$$|f'(x)| > 3|x|,$$ 
when $x = \sqrt[3]{k\pi}$, $k\in \Bbb Z - \{0\}$.

---

**EDIT** Thanks to the discussion with [Allawonder](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/145126/allawonder) and the amazing counterexample given by [user21820](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21820/user21820), I learned, that, rather counterintuitively, even differentiable functions that monotonically tend to an horizontal (or slant) asymptote, may have unbounded derivative.

Here I add nothing to what [user21820](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21820/user21820) very precisely wrote in his answer and following comments (of which I thank him). I just want to add another counterexample of that kind, simpler than his, at the cost of losing infinite differentiability.

Take

$$t(x) = \begin{cases} 1-|x| & (|x|\leq 1) \\ 0 & (|x| > 1)\end{cases}$$

and define

$$g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} (2k-1) t\left((2k-1)k^2(x-2k+1)\right).$$

The function is sketched below.

[image]

It is easy to verify that the area of the $k$th triangle is $\frac1{k^2}$.

So if we now define

$$f(x) = \int_0^{x} g(t)dt$$

we obtain a monotonically increasing function, with

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

with unbounded derivative.

Comment: Yes, I think it was OP idea to consider boundedness only where the asymptotic behaviour actually occurs. So showing a counter-example for this case is nice. We often forget convergence can happen while oscilating like crazy.

Comment: @zwim, incredibly, at least for me, you may have unboundedness of the derivative even without oscillation below and above the asymptote... Se my edit and, above all, the other answer!

Comment: Thanks for putting up a simple illustrated example with the same core idea! You may be interested in knowing that it is easy to use a suitably squashed [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) for each spike, in order to get an infinitely differentiable unbounded derivative. I was aiming for the shortest formula in my post. =P

Comment: @user21820 Nice! I was looking for something of that kind, yesterday. But wasn't able to find it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

No, consider the exponential function $f(x) = e^x$ defined for all real numbers. It has a horizontal asymptote (the horizontal $x$-axis) but has no vertical asymptote (by vertical asymptote I assume you mean something like $1/x^2$ at $x=0$) however, its derivative $f'=f$ is unbounded.

Comment: It is bounded *below*, however... and that's the direction the asymptote goes in!

Comment: @Kevin Im afraid I don't see what you're trying to get at; could you elaborate? I gave an example with horizontal asymptote, no vertical asymptote and such that it's derivative is unbounded, which is what a counterexample should do?

Comment: @kevin take $f(x) = e^x \sin x$. The function also has the same horizontal asymptote as $e^x$ but has an unbounded derivative in both directions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: The reason that OP is asking this question is because they (incorrectly) believe that "if the derivative is unbounded in either direction, then the function cannot have a horizontal asymptote in that direction, because the unbounded derivative should take it away from its horizontal asymptote." A good counterexample should rebut *that intuition* and not just the question as literally asked.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f$ on $(0,∞)$ defined by $f(x) = \sin(x^3)/x$ for every $x∈(0,∞)$.

It has a horizontal asymptote at $∞$, but obviously has unbounded derivative.

A natural question that arises is whether the derivative must always be bounded if the function is differentiable and monotonically approaches a non-vertical asymptote (i.e. the difference between the function and the asymptote tends monotonically to zero). The answer is **still no**.

Consider the function $g$ on $(0,∞)$ defined by $g(x) = \int_0^x t·(\cos(t)^2)^{t^4}\ dt$ for every $x∈(0,∞)$. (In case you cannot see, the outer exponent is $t^4$.) Note that the squaring of $\cos(t)$ is to ensure that the outer exponentiation is well-defined.

Then clearly $g$ is monotonically increasing, and I'll leave it as a fun exercise for you to prove that $g$ is bounded, and hence $g$ has a horizontal asymptote. But $g'(x) = x·(\cos(x)^2)^{x^4}$, which is clearly unbounded even as $x→∞$. Moreover, $g$ is infinitely differentiable!

Hints for the exercise:

> (1) $c^{t^4} ≤ c^{(k·π)^4}$ for every $c ≥ 0$ and $t∈[k,k+1]·π$.
>  (2) To bound $\int_0^{π/2} (\cos(t)^2)^{p^4}\ dt$, prove that $\cos(t)^2 ≤ \exp(-t^2/2)$ for every $t∈[0,π/2]$, and so $\int_0^{π/2} (\cos(t)^2)^{p^4}\ dt ≤ \int_0^{π/2} \exp(-p^4·t^2/2)\ dt = \int_0^{π/2} \exp(-t^2/2)\ dt / p^2$.

Comment: Beautiful. I'll read it through as soon as I can. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Wow! One should really be wary of intuition.

Comment: Your example made me wonder about the identity $f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{g(x) \log f(x)}$. This would imply that points for which $f(x)\leq 0$, and in particular $f(x)=0$, cannot be included in the domain. Is that false?

Comment: @dfnu: There are 3 different and incompatible definitions of exponentiation. The first one that is good for complex analysis is $x^y := \exp(y·\ln_π(x))$, where $\ln_π$ is the standard branch cut of $\ln$ defined everywhere except at $0$, such that $\ln(x)$ is the unique $t$ with $\exp(t) = x$ and $Im(t)∈(-π,π]$. $\ln_π$ is differentiable everywhere except the non-positive real line and continuous at the negative real line from above. But $\ln_π(0)$ is still ill-defined, so if we use this definition then your identity is true for $f(x),g(x) ∈ \mathbb{C}∖(-∞,0]$ (but ill-defined otherwise).

Comment: The second definition that is good for real analysis is sketched [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1790356/21820) and starts with defining integer and then rational exponentiation, and using Cauchy sequences to jump to real exponentiation. In that post I explained why we can sensibly define $x^{1/n}$ for any real $x$ and odd $n$, but I didn't say much more. Nevertheless you can check that we can have $x^r$ well-defined for any real $x ≥ 0$ and rational $r ≥ 0$. This definition is useful in real life, since we often use it (such as $\sqrt{0} = 0$ in standard deviation).

Comment: The third definition that is found in some real analysis textbooks also starts with rational exponentiation but uses the supremum axiom to jump to real exponentiation, as sketched in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1658512/21820). Note that certain properties of exponentiation do not hold for exponentiation permitting base $0$. For instance, $0^0 = 1$ but $0^r = 0$ for every positive rational $r$. Both the 2nd and 3rd definitions extend to $0^r$ for positive real $r$, because positive rational exponents behave nicely even with zero base, and that is what we need in my above post.

Comment: @dfnu: In short, for real analysis, we can define $x^y$ so that it is defined for any reals $x,y$ such that either $x > 0$ or ( $x = 0$ and $y > 0$ ), and retain most nice properties of exponentiation that we would like, including algebraic identities and continuity on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit-Edit:* From the answer of @user21820 it appears that even in the case where a function monotonically approaches an asymptote it still doesn't follow that the derivative should be bounded at infinity. This is a real lesson in the possibility of being badly misled by intuition.

---

*Edit:* As the counterexamples of @dfnu show, having an asymptote at infinity doesn't imply a bounded derivative near infinity, as I assumed in my previous answer below. I'm leaving this because I think you were thinking along similar lines. I wouldn't normally think of a snaky curve as being asymptotic, but it fits the definition nicely, so one has to admit that this is not true in general. It's probably true only for curves that are *monotonically* asymptotic to a line -- which were the only type I'd (insufficiently) had in mind while composing the previous answer below.

---

I see what might have led you into this thinking. Having a nonvertical  asymptote means the derivative has a limiting value at $\pm \infty,$ but that's all that one can conclude -- without additional hypothesis.

Thus, it doesn't follow that if a function has a limiting value then it is bounded -- except for some classes of functions -- namely those defined on $(-\infty,a]$ or $[a,+\infty)$ for some real $a,$ and which are continuous at their finite endpoints, or else those defined on $(-\infty,+\infty)$ *and* having asymptotes at **both** "endpoints". That is, you've been implicitly (if my retracing of your thinking is correct) making the assumption that your function should be defined only on half-open intervals with one infinite endpoint and continuous at the finite endpoint -- or else it must have asymptotes at both $+\infty$ and $-\infty.$ These are additional conditions that guarantee that the derivative is bounded.

So, for example, you might originally have been thinking of something like the arctangent function defined on the real line. Thus, if a function is defined and continuously differentiable on $\mathbf R,$ and it has asymptotes at both $+\infty$ and $-\infty,$ then it's derivative should be bounded. If it's defined and continuously differentiable on either $(-\infty,a]$ or $[a,+\infty),$ and it has an asymptote at $\pm \infty,$ then again the derivative is bounded. An example of such would be the exponential function defined for $x\ge 0.$

I think this was what you had in mind. Now that we have clarified the problem can you try to find a proof?

Comment: I also thought that that was what the OP might have thought; but be careful, your statement is **false** in general. See my examples. It is easy to show that having bounded derivative at infinity is neither necessary nor sufficient condition to have a non vertical asymptote.

Comment: Just remove the discontinuity in $0$ in my examples, and you've got the counterexample of your statement.

Comment: If you need a counterexample of your statement, as a matter of fact, $x^2$ in the argument is sufficient.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin x^2}{x} & (x\neq 0) \\ 0 & (x=0)\end{cases}$$

is continuously differentiable everywhere, and does have horizontal asymptotes, but the limit 

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$$

does not exist. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I might be misreading, but I read many times and thouroughly. And both "Thus, if a function is defined and continuously differentiable on R, and it has asymptotes at both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, then it's derivative should be bounded" and "Having a nonvertical asymptote means the derivative has a limiting value at $\pm \infty$, but that's all that one can conclude -- without additional hypothesis" are false statement. And I don't see the restriction you're mentioning. Can you point that out better?

Comment: @dfnu Sorry, I was the one not paying sufficient attention. I think you were right. My problem was my idea of an asymptote didn't involve sinuous ones, LOL! Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: No problem, we are both here to learn :)

Comment: Probably something can be said **if** the difference between $f(x)$ and the asymptote is, for sufficiently high $x$, monotonically going to $0$.

Comment: @dfnu Yeah, *monotony* is the word. That was exactly what had been in my mind all along, until your example made me question my understanding of the definition of *asymptote.*

Comment: @dfnu: No; see my answer.